# Bash: Overriding paths in a make file

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I am creating a bash script that uses a local copy of gcc for arm.  I need to have multiple versions of gcc around for compatibility.  My bash script downloads the binary correctly, sets up the path locally but the make files ignore the local version.

After reading some docs [make: Using Environment Variables](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC68) I found that there is an `export -e OPTION=VALUE` from a bash script that will override the make default path.

This works well in my local copy of bash, but when running it through circle testing servers it fails, saying that `-e` is an invalid option.

Anyone know of a better way to override paths inside of make?  Specifically for a third party project that I can't change the make files for.

```
GCC_ARM_VER=gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q2    
export -e GCC_ARM_PATH=$BINDIR/gcc-arm-embedded/$GCC_ARM_VER/bin
export PATH=$GCC_ARM_PATH:$PATH
make all -s -C "$BASE_FIRMWARE/"firmware APPDIR="$CWD/firmware" TARGET_DIR="$CWD/bin" PLATFORM="$1" || exit
```

And then in the make file (arm-tools.mk):

```
    # Define the compiler/tools prefix
    GCC_PREFIX ?= arm-none-eabi-

    include $(COMMON_BUILD)/common-tools.mk

    AR = $(GCC_ARM_PATH)$(GCC_PREFIX)gcc-ar

    #
    # default flags for targeting ARM
    #

    # C compiler flags
    CFLAGS +=  -g3 -gdwarf-2 -Os -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb

    # C++ specific flags
    CPPFLAGS += -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fcheck-new

    CONLYFLAGS +=

    ASFLAGS +=  -g3 -gdwarf-2 -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb

    LDFLAGS += -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections

    ...
```

Comment: I think you misread `make` manual. As said here https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_9.html#SEC92 `-e` is `make` option, not `export` option. Back to your question - is `GCC_ARM_PATH` set somewhere in your `arm-tools.mk` before it's used?

Comment: If you must fix something, arguments set on the command line to `make` cannot be overridden (in the top-level `make`) by either the environment or the makefile.  The normal precedence hierarchy (highest to lowest) is command-line argument, makefile, environment; the `make -e` option changes that to command-line argument, environment, makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify what Jonathan said, you don't want to use `export -e` and you don't want to use `make -e` and you don't need to modify the makefiles.  All you have to do if you want your variable assignment to take precedence is to add it to the make command line:

```
GCC_ARM_VER=gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q2
export PATH=$GCC_ARM_PATH:$PATH
make all -s -C "$BASE_FIRMWARE/"firmware \
    APPDIR="$CWD/firmware" TARGET_DIR="$CWD/bin" PLATFORM="$1" \
    GCC_ARM_PATH="$BINDIR/gcc-arm-embedded/$GCC_ARM_VER/bin" \
  || exit
```